# On removing extends basic controller getting 500 internal server error on api call

Tags: php, extends

I am working with a api where i have two classes in seperate files please check the below code.

### location.class.php

```
class GenericLocation extends controller {
   // some methods
}
```

### customer.class.php

```
include \DOC_ROOT . "libs/location.class.php";
class CustomerLocation extends GenericLocation {

    function __construct() {  
        parent::__construct(); 
    }

   // some methods
}
```

It works fine if this the code.

If i remove the extends controller (which is irrelevant) in location.class.php it is giving me internal server error when i make a api call in browser.

Comment: 500 error can come becuase of syntax error ,server configuration error or file permission error so you should check out that why this error is coming.. you can see your error log file

Comment: i believe there is no parent construction in GenericLocation if you don't extent the controller then how can you call the parent::__construct in customer.class.php

Comment: can you elaborate on this topic am bit new to this.

Comment: when you remove the extends controller then also remove the parent::__construct() from customer.class.php and check it is working or not

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks for the fix. But i want to know what exactly parent::__construct() does.

Comment: parent::__construct() : it means that you are overridding the parent class's construct method but if you are not extending any parent class then how can you call the parent class's construct method